# adding index to email column culprit for unit tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, devise, indexing

I am new to devise and rails and I just integrated devise with my sample app. What I noticed is after creating a *user* model, all my unit tests were failing. I went to try to narrow this and found that even the generated assert 'the truth' one for `user_test.rb` also fails:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: \
    column email is not unique: INSERT INTO "users" (...
```

Once I commented out the `add_index` ...

```
# add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
```

... and re-ran `rake db:test:load` and re-run tests with `ruby -I test test/unit/user_test.rb` it passes.

Has anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 55):

If you just generated the devise model, a fixture was also generated with more or less this content:

```
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
#  column: value
```

This fixture tries to create two users, with the same (inexistant) email. Replace it by:

```
one:
  email: test1@test.com

two:
  email: test2@test.com
```

It will fix this error.

Comment: thanks Geal, I got side tracked but I noticed the same issue just now.  Thanks!

Comment: I get this other error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table for all my tests.  After deleting the users fixture file or disabling fixtures :all in the test helper, I was able to get past these errors.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  I'll get by for now.

Comment: looks like you didn't launch the database migrations

Answer (score 1):

The failure would have to be happening in the test setup, before the actual test.  You are probably trying to set up users with identical email addresses, either via fixtures or factories.

If you are using fixtures, make sure each user is given a different email address.  If you are using factories, use a sequence to generate a unique email addresses for each user that's created.

Comment: HI Steve, this is not the case with duplicate fixture data.  I am using factories (with sequencing on email) but for this particular model Users, which is generated for Devise, I am only testing the 'assert the truth' testcase, which should always return true.  there is no fixture data or anything.  i cleaned out my database , made sure to update schema.rb doing rake db:migrate and deleting the test database and redo the test from scratch.  i suspect there is some bug with adding index and unit tests but i did not dig down that rabbit hole just yet.

Comment: sql generated appears to be (w/ values in insert statement) incorrect:ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: column email is not unique: INSE
RT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2011-04-24 08:53:36', '2011-04-24
 08:53:36', 298486374)