# rails strange unit test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I try to run this simplest unit test:

```
   test "the truth" do
     assert true
   end
```

like this:

```
ruby -Itest test/unit/my_model_test.rb
```

(there is the only one test in the file, and actually in the whole site)

it fails with this message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: column email is not unique: INSERT INTO "users"... [some values to insert here]
```

now I do have a table named "users" but other than that I have never asked to do any tests on it nor do I even have such tests. Where does this error come from? How do I run just my test?

EDIT: the "users" table comes from the devise gem if that helps

Comment: Can you post full stack trace? Do you have fixtures in your project? May be they are loaded into DB that wasn't properly cleared.

Comment: Is that all the code in my_model_test.rb?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quote from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

> Rails by default automatically loads all fixtures from the
>   test/fixtures folder for your unit and functional test. Loading
>   involves three steps:
>
> - Remove any existing data from the table corresponding to the fixture
> - Load the fixture data into the table
> - Dump the fixture data into a
>     variable in case you want to access it directly

So I think you need to check those fixtures. Also I suggest you to read that tutorial. It is very well written.

Comment: you are right. more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769758/adding-index-to-email-column-culprit-for-unit-tests-failing