# Error: SessionsControllerTest#test_should_get_new: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am use ruby -v 2.2.3 & rails -v 4.2.4 . I am tried to test after login upon signup using $ bundle exec rake test command but lots of error throw by terminal.Errors are
1) Error:
SessionsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Error:
SessionsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

2) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

3) Error:
ZapsControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Error:
ZapsControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

4) Error:
ZapsControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Error:
ZapsControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

5) Error:
ZapsControllerTest#test_should_get_contact:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Error:
ZapsControllerTest#test_should_get_contact:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

6) Error:
ZapsControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Error:
ZapsControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

7) Error:
SiteLayoutTest#test_layout_links:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Error:
SiteLayoutTest#test_layout_links:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

8) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup_information:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup_information:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

9) Error:
UserTest#test_password_should_have_a_minimum_length:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

10) Error:
UserTest#test_name_should_be_present:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

11) Error:
UserTest#test_email_should_not_be_too_long:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

12) Error:
UserTest#test_email_validation_should_reject_invalid_addresses:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

13) Error:
UserTest#test_email_should_be_present:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

14) Error:
UserTest#test_password_should_be_present_(nonblank):
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

15) Error:
UserTest#test_should_be_valid:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

16) Error:
UserTest#test_name_should_not_be_too_long:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

17) Error:
UserTest#test_email_addresses_should_be_unique:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

18) Error:
UserTest#test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

19) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_invalid_information:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_invalid_information:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

20) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

20 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 20 errors, 0 skips

Code in users.yml file is

## Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

pankaj:
name: Pankaj
email: pankajbarhate13@gmail.com
password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

Plase give me solution to solve the problem.

Comment: Stackoverflow is the place to ask concrete questions about specific problems - you can't just dump your entire project in a question and expect someone to do your job for you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too much confusing. its seams that some of your object is not initialized. Check all the objects on which you are calling .each.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this exact error. After digging around I found the following Stack Overflow question: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396144/rails-tutorial-nomethoderror-undefined-method-each-for-nilnilclass)

I had an issue with on of my fixtures. I started to add attributes to `one:` but stopped, I removed the braces but never added any yml attributes.

Here is the generated code

```
one: {}
```

Here was my broken yml

```
one:
```

Simply add the `{}` back and everything worked. You're syntax error may be the result of some other illegal yml format, but I hope this helps someone else down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

If you have users.yml file in /test/fixtures commit all the lines there

Comment: for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279403/rails-strange-unit-test-fails