# All tests failing and ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, railstutorial.org

Doing the rails tutorial and everything was fine and then all of a sudden my tests all failed.

There seems to be an issue with the Users database, but I haven't touched it.

I deleted my SQL file and re set it up. Then re migrated and re tested, still the same result.

ERRORS

```
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (log-in-log-out) $ bundle exec rake test
Run options: --seed 51875
# Running:
...................
Finished in 0.974929s, 19.4886 runs/s, 47.1829 assertions/s.
19 runs, 46 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (log-in-log-out) $ bundle exec rake test
Run options: --seed 18295
# Running:
...................
Finished in 1.007973s, 18.8497 runs/s, 51.5887 assertions/s.
19 runs, 52 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (log-in-log-out) $ rails g migration add_remember_digest_to_users remember:digest:string
invoke active_record
create db/migrate/20160110153840_add_remember_digest_to_users.rb
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (log-in-log-out) $ bundle exec rake db:migrate
== 20160110153840 AddRememberDigestToUsers: migrating =========================
-- add_column(:users, :remember, :digest)
-> 0.0012s
== 20160110153840 AddRememberDigestToUsers: migrated (0.0014s) ================
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (log-in-log-out) $ bundle exec rake test
Run options: --seed 58894
# Running:
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
Finished in 0.089546s, 212.1804 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_invalid_information:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_invalid_information:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
2) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
3) Error:
SessionsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
SessionsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
4) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup_information:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup_information:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
5) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
6) Error:
UserTest#test_email_validation_should_reject_invalid_addresses:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
7) Error:
UserTest#test_should_be_valid:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
8) Error:
UserTest#test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
9) Error:
UserTest#test_name_should_be_present:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
10) Error:
UserTest#test_name_should_not_be_too_long:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
11) Error:
UserTest#test_email_should_be_present:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
12) Error:
UserTest#test_email_addresses_should_be_unique:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
13) Error:
UserTest#test_email_should_not_be_too_long:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
14) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
15) Error:
SiteLayoutTest#test_layout_links:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
SiteLayoutTest#test_layout_links:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
16) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_contact:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_contact:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
17) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
18) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
19) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
19 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 19 errors, 0 skips
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (log-in-log-out) $ bundle exec rake test
Run options: --seed 19458
```

SECOND ROUND OF ERRORS AFTER REGENERATING TO FIX TYPO

```
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (log-in-log-out) $ rails generate migration add_remember_digest_to_users remember_digest:string
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160117220806_add_remember_digest_to_users.rb
rs191919:~/workspace/sample_app (log-in-log-out) $ bundle exec rake db:migrate
== 20160117220806 AddRememberDigestToUsers: migrating =========================
-- add_column(:users, :remember_digest, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "remember_digest" varchar/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:453:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_t me'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/db/migrate/20160117220806_add_remember_digest_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "remember_digest" varchar
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:453:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/db/migrate/20160117220806_add_remember_digest_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:453:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/db/migrate/20160117220806_add_remember_digest_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: You probably dropped your database without realizing it. Why don't you drop and recreate the database and then try your tests again. `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed` On second thought... you're using rake db:test:prepare, which is deprecated. Are you sure you're testing against the correct database?

Comment: @MarsAtomic yea i think so. been running the same test for the whole project. none of my test files have changed since this happened. just ran those tests and same result.

Comment: db:test:prepare got undeprecated (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17739/files). What's this .sql file you say your deleted? Does your development database have a users table?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I recreated test.sqlite3. i updated the ERRORs above to show what was happening before the errors came.

Comment: `add_column(:users, :remember, :digest)`  ... what is `:digest` doing there?  What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a typo here: `remember:digest:string`. It should be `remember_digest:string`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have users.yml file in /test/fixtures commit all the lines there

From more information:
[rails strange unit test fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279403/rails-strange-unit-test-fails)